# Reporting Services - hide table column based upon report parameter

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report in Reporting Services 2005, and I want to hide or show a single table column based upon a report parameter.  Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the Visibility for the column to an expression which will return true or false. This property can be found on in the Visibility tab on a TextBox for example.

Click the radio option for Expression and then your expression might look like

```
=Parameters!ShowColumn.Value
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, I am actually going to use the Hidden property (a sub property of visibility [at least in vs 2005]) for the column.

Answer (score 10):

Use the visibility property of the column. This worked for me.

```
=iif(Parameters!ParameterName.Value = "TextValueOfTheParameter",False,True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tip: If the expression returns "False" then the column or row will be visible.  If the expression returns "True", the expression will be hidden.  This tricked me at first.

Answer (score 2):

For some of my reports I've set the Visibility (Specifically the **Hidden** property) for the **column** to:

```
=IsNothing(Fields!Site.Value)
```

Note that this only works if the relevant field can be null in the underlying dataset, otherwise you will see the blank column.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s say my report(SSRS 2005) have 5 columns.  And I want to show/ hide columns based on a parameter(multi select with all 5 column names) selected by user. do as following

1)Create a parameter of type string (ColumnVisibility is name of my parameter) with desired column names in labels for the 5 columns and **INT** number(01,02,03,04,05) respectively in the values in “Available Values” section of the parameter wizard.

2) Then Go to column Properties on design . Go to “visibility” and paste following

```
=iif(instr(Join(Parameters!ColumnVisibility.Value,","),"01")>0,false,true)
```

3) repeat same for all the columns, by increasing the int value by 1..see following for example

2nd column

```
=iif(instr(Join(Parameters!ColumnVisibility.Value,","),"**02**")>0,false,true)
```

3rd column

```
=iif(instr(Join(Parameters!ColumnVisibility.Value,","),"**03**")>0,false,true)
```

And so on. For SSRS 2008, when you right click on the column you can see "Column Visibility" option. paste the code in  "show or hide based on an expression" section for each column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide whole column, when there are no data at all for that specific column in the report, you can use following code in the column visibility/expression:

```
=IIF(IsNothing (Sum(Fields!columnA.Value, "ReportA")),False,True)
```

Comment: What is "ReportA" here ? Dataset ?

Answer (score 0):

when I do as above, I can make the column disappear but it leaves a gap in my table. Is this the expected result. I was hoping the columns would also shift over. I'm trying to hind a column for one group and then display it for the next group.

Answer (score 0):

To make a null column disappear,

Right-Click column to select Column Visibility, then Set expression for Hidden:

```
IIF(IsNothing(Fields!FieldName.Value),True,False)
```